Reading building addresses out of GML-files via citygml4j
i would like to extract the address of a building to continue working with it. Which building is not important for now (can be the first building found in the gml-file). If i want to read the address via "getAdresses" it shows me the UUID from the model itself.
Do you know a method of getting the city, street and postcode of a building?
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Logger log = Logger.start(SimpleReader.class);

    // Initialisiere den CityGML-Kontext und die InputFactory
    CityGMLContext context = CityGMLContext.newInstance();
    CityGMLInputFactory in = context.createCityGMLInputFactory();

    // Lade die GML-Datei
    Path file = Util.SAMPLE_DATA_DIR.resolve("lod3_building_v2.gml");
    log.print("Reading the file " + file + " into main memory");

    // Öffne und lese die CityGML-Datei
    try (CityGMLReader reader = in.createCityGMLReader(file)) {
        CityModel cityModel = (CityModel) reader.next();

        if (cityModel != null) {
            log.print("CityModel gefunden. Suche nach Adressen...");

            // Durchlaufe CityModel-Objekte, um das erste Gebäude zu finden
            for (AbstractCityObjectProperty cityObjectMember : cityModel.getCityObjectMembers()) {
                AbstractCityObject object = cityObjectMember.getObject();

                if (object instanceof Building building) {
                    log.print("Erstes Gebäude gefunden.");
                    log.print("Test");
                    // Prüfen, ob Adressdaten vorhanden sind
                    for (AddressProperty addressProperty : building.getAddresses()) {
                        Address address = addressProperty.getObject();
                        log.print("TEST " + address.toString());
                        if (address != null && address.getXALAddress() != null) {
                            XALAddressProperty xalAddress = address.getXALAddress();
                            String thoroughfareName = address.getXALAddress().toString();
                                    //.filter(line -> line.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("ThoroughfareName"))
                                    //.map(line -> line.getContent())
                                    //.findFirst();
                            if (thoroughfareName.isEmpty()) {
                                log.print("Straßenname (ThoroughfareName): " + thoroughfareName);
                            } 
                            else {
                                log.print("ThoroughfareName gefunden: " + thoroughfareName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break; // Nur das erste Gebäude verarbeiten
                }
            }
        } else {
            log.print("Kein CityModel im GML gefunden.");
        }
    }

    log.finish();
}

